# apscheduler: how to add jobid, jobname and other details in mongodbjobstore

Tags: apscheduler

I am using apscheduler python library to schedule jobs. It have jobstores where
nextruntime gets stored. My question is how we can add more details of respective job store. I have shared a image as how its being stored right now.

```
mongo= MongoClient("localhost",27017)

job_stores = {
       'default': MongoDBJobStore(database="logs",client=mongo,collection="schedulejob")
   }
executors = {
       'default': {'type': 'threadpool', 'max_workers': 60}
   }
job_defaults = {
       'coalesce': True,  # When the same task is triggered multiple times at the same time, it runs only once
       'max_instances': 3,
       'misfire_grace_time': 30,  # The task is still executed after 30 seconds of expiration
}

sched = BackgroundScheduler(jobstores=job_stores, executors=executors, job_defaults=job_defaults, daemon=True)
    sched.add_job(syncdata, 'interval', minutes=5, kwargs={"subdomain": "d3v-digite", "emailid": "sp"},
                  name="incrementaljob")
    sched.add_listener(listen, EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED | EVENT_JOB_ERROR)
sched.start()
```

In mongojob store following is stored:
[image: Mongodb job store]

Answer (score 2):

You can get some details from the database. You have `job_state`.
In MongoDBJobStore you can find a method called `lookup_job`.

Or use this:

```
def lookup_job(self, job_id):
    document = self.collection.find_one(job_id, ['job_state'])
    return self._reconstitute_job(document['job_state']) if document else None
```

Also you can decode job_state in that way:

```
job_state = pickle.loads(job_state)
```

And if all is OK, you will receive a dictionary with a lot of useful data, for example:

```
{'version': 1, 'id': 'feef92e4832642ae8361bcf6fd0f6fef', 'func': '', 'trigger': <CronTrigger (month='*', day='*', day_of_week='*', hour='*', minute='8', timezone='UTC')>, 'executor': 'default', 'args': ['scheduler.jobs.curl_job.CurlJob', 'feef92e4832642ae8361bcf6fd0f6fef', 'scheduler.corescheduler.datastore.providers.mongodb.DatastoreMongoDB', {'user': '', 'password': '', 'hostname': '', 'port': , 'database': ''}, {'jobs_tablename': '', 'executions_tablename': 'scheduler_execution', 'auditlogs_tablename': 'scheduler_jobauditlog'}, 'http://localhost/jobs', 'GET'], 'kwargs': {'job_name': 'Awesome_job_222'}, 'name': 'Awesome_job_222', 'misfire_grace_time': 3600, 'coalesce': True, 'max_instances': 3, 'next_run_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 24, 15, 8, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community, @dmk. This is a useful first contribution. I appreciate that you provided both explanation and code. Please keep up the good work.